# HTML5 Video not working on web server (all browsers)

Tags: html, html5-video

I tested my video tags on localhost and it is working, after uploading it to a web server and check it, it is not working. I am 100% sure that I reference my videos correctly using a relative path. I also included the following on my .htaccess:

```
 AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg 
 AddType video/webm .webm
 AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Here's my video tags:

```
 <video autoplay  poster="images/background-1.jpg" id="bgvid" loop>
    <source src="vids/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="vids/vid.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Not working in what way?

Comment: Video is not playing

Comment: Do you see the video being downloaded in the network tab? What does the console show?